# PHP display date as month name and date

Tags: php, date

I am getting current date using the function `date("Y-m-d")`.
I want to display date `2017-09-12` as `sep 12`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php there is "M" for a 3 letter abbreviation for month.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: You are not tried anything and where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can present it as ("M j"). [Here](https://3v4l.org/JlRkl) is a test version.

Comment: Question shows lowercased month.

Comment: If you want to transform it to lowercase, just use strtolower().
Here's an example : https://3v4l.org/kn1lM

Answer (score 0):

this will do: `date_format($date,"M/d");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your date..

```
$myDate = "2017-09-12";
```

Then you have to convert your date with `Date` PHP function

```
$date = date("M d",mktime("0 0 0 ".$myDate));
```

echo `$date` will print `Sep 12`

`d` is Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

`M` is a short textual representation of a month, three letters